# Use a value from a subclass in my main class if a property in main class is set to false

Tags: c#, getter

The sub class isn't derived from the main class, I'm just trying to differentiate them.

Even as I type this I can see it being impossible but I have some classes:

```
public class TransferServiceInformation {
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }
    public string PrePurchaseOverride { get; set; }
    public bool PrePurchaseOverrideEnabled { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class TransferServiceProviderInformation {
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }
    public string PrePurchaseInfo { get; set; }
```

And I want it so that if I ever try to access `myTransferServiceInformation.PrePurchaseOverride` and `PrePurchaseOverrideEnabled == false` it should return `PrePurchaseInfo` from the `TransferServiceProviderInformation` with the same ID.

Is something like that even possible?

I'm just having a thought that a getter that requires a `TransferServiceProviderInformation` passed as an argument might work, and throw an exception if the IDs don't match. Is that the only solution? The thing is, I'd rather not have to dig through all the (thousands of lines of) code to change all the places were I (or someone else) has called this property.

Comment: I guess you are creating instances of both classes. If accessing `PrePurchaseOverride` with `Instance1`, how should this class know about the possible existance  of `Instance2` for `TransferServiceProviderInformation`? Are those instances saved into lists somewhere?

Comment: @C4u well exactly, this is why I was thinking it was impossible. No, they're not in any kind of static list or something (or at least, I can't guarantee it since I'm not familiar with 95% of the code). I think setting the getter to private and making a new one that requires the 'parent' `TransferServiceProviderInformation` passed as an argument is going to be my only solution.

Comment: Ah ok. So Im at least on the right point. I've got an idea. Will post in some secs.

Comment: if there is no list or repository, how are you populating/creating TransferServiceProviderInformation then for a specfic ProviderId ? Are you getting it directly from the Database?

Comment: Can you solve this with the decorator pattern? From the perspective of the class consumers, They should be even unaware it is being overridden.

Comment: @Nitin
There is a database yes, and I don't know that somewhere someone hasn't called the database just to get the information for one provider and returned that.

Comment: @MauriceStam That sounds good but I don't know what that is (it's only my second week as a programmer!) Can you add an answer?

Comment: @captainjamie without pattern experience, and for me no insight in your architecture, I would not recommend proceeding with this. Given the situation and the amount of refactoring required, you might want to consult a more experienced developer on the matter, with knowledge of the architecture of your solution. For us, it is just to broad. We can give random suggestions but we cannot judge which one suits the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is just an idea:**

Make a static list with instances inside your class and auto-fill it with using the constructor. Then you can check this list from outside for instances with the same id.

```
public class TransferServiceInformation
{
    public int ProviderId { get; set; }

    private string prePurchaseOverride;
    public string PrePurchaseOverride
    {
        get
        {
            if(!PrePurchaseOverrideEnabled)
            {
                // Get instances from the other class where providerID matches
                var instance = TransferServiceProviderInformation.Instances.Where(i => i.ProviderId == this.ProviderId).FirstOrDefault();
                if(instance != null)
                return (instance).PrePurchaseInfo;
            }
            return null; // If no match found
        }
        set
        {
            prePurchaseOverride = value;
        }
    }

    private bool prePurchaseOverrideEnabled;
    public bool PrePurchaseOverrideEnabled { get; set; }
}

public class TransferServiceProviderInformation
{
    // Store your instances static
    public static List<TransferServiceProviderInformation> Instances { get; set; }

    public TransferServiceProviderInformation()
    {
        // Add every new instance to the list
        Instances.Add(this);
    }

    public int ProviderId { get; set; }
    public string PrePurchaseInfo { get; set; }
}
```

**To-do's:**

If an instance gets disposed, delete it from the list of instances.